# Opening specific pdf files from database in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

What I want to do is to access a file by its name from a Database and show it onscreen in a new window. I have this working locally if i store the file in my project and not in my DB. I have done this by:

**Views.py**

```
def show_file(response):
pdf = open( `chartsapp/faults.pdf`, 'rb')
response = FileResponse(pdf)
return response
```

**Url.py**

```
path('show_file/', views.show_file),
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="Show Report" onclick="window.open('show_file')">
```

My code above will open my locally store `faults.pdf`, and who it in a new window called `show_file`.

Taking this as a baseline i have been trying to swap out `chartsapp/faults.pdf` for the path to my database. So I thought that the following would access my `faults.pdf` which has been stored in my database called 'UploadedFile`:

**Views.py**

```
def show_file(response):
    pdf = open( UploadedFile.the_file('faults.pdf'), 'rb')
    response = FileResponse(pdf)
    return response
```

I thought this should work because i am first accessing my Database called `UploadedFile`, then the `the_file` object, the entry called `faults.pdf`. But I am missing something as this does not work.